# Simplify a JavaScript / Typescript helper function which returns an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, helper

I have this json object:

```
const data = {
  one: {
    items: [
      {
        title: 'Home',
        url: '',
      },
      {
        title: 'Title test',
        url: '/test',
      },
    ],
  },
  two: {
    items: [
      {
        title: 'Title test 2',
        url: '/test2',
      },
      {
        title: 'Title test 2',
        url: '/test2',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I created below (javascript and typescript) helper function which returns an array of `items` from object key `one` or `two`:

```
interface Item {
  title: string;
  url: string;
}

const getItems = (key?: 'one') => {
  if (key === 'one') {
    return data.one.items.map((item: Item) => ({
      title: item.title,
      url: item.url,
    }));
  }
  return data.two.items.map((item: Item) => ({
      title: item.title,
      url: item.url,
    }));
};
```

Then I can use it like:

```
const items = getItems('one');


items.map((item) => (
 <li>{item.title}</li>
));
```

Can I simplify this helper and get the same result?

Comment: Why do you need a helper function? It's just `const items = data.one.items;` or `const items = data.two.items;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simplify it:

```
const getItems = (key) => data[key].items;
```

if you want a typed one:

```
const getItems = (key: 'one' | 'two') => data[key].items;
```

if you want to be more generic

```
const getItems = (key: keyof typeof data) => data[key].items;
```

if you want a full clone (i.e. new list of new items)

```
const getItems = (key) => data[key].items.map(x => ({...x}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part of your question, where you say that the code is not working properly, I think you just got confused with the default value and the type for the `key` parameter of the `getItems` function. If you would like to define the parameter type of the `key` parameter, you should be using `keyof typeof data`, which essentially tells typescript that the `key` parameter accepts one of the keys of the data object. The code would look something like this

```
interface Item {
  title: string;
  url: string;
}

const getItems = (key: keyof typeof data='one') => {
  if (key === 'one') {
    return data.one.items.map((item: Item) => ({
      title: item.title,
      url: item.url,
    }));
  }
  return data.two.items.map((item: Item) => ({
      title: item.title,
      url: item.url,
    }));
};
```

Coming to the second part of your question on a simplified solution, this might help

```
const getItemsSimplified = (key: keyof typeof data='one') => {
  return data[key]?.items.map((item: Item) => ({
      title: item.title,
      url: item.url,
    }));
};
```

Check out the [complete working code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=57&ssc=3&pln=52&pc=1#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-3N4td+PpfLga8L6AA) for both the parts of your question.